# Displaying buttons

Tags: scripting

I'm trying to display my buttons, and what I'd like to change is the middle button to take up more space. Like double or triple the size, because right now the 3 buttons are evenly spaced.

This is the current code:

```
layout = self.layout
row = layout.row()
row.operator("mybutton.button1", text="Button 1")
row.operator("mybutton.button2", text="Button 2")
row.operator("mybutton.button3", text="Button 3")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the ui_panel.py template in the text editor, you can see this:

[image: demo ui panel]

Adapting this to your code, it would look like this:

```py
layout = self.layout
row = layout.row()
row.operator("mybutton.button1", text="Button 1")
sub = row.row()
sub.scale_x = 2.0
sub.operator("mybutton.button2", text="Button 2")
row.operator("mybutton.button3", text="Button 3")
```